# Best way to generate mysql table primary key string+number

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Can someone suggest best method to generate table primary key containing string and a number. Like,

```
EMP00001
EMP00002
```

I want to do this by minimizing error possibilities. So should I do this in mysql or with the c# server code. If someone can provide example that would be really helpful.

Comment: Noticed your using EMP, if that is for an employee ID, then probably best to keep a column for the number part, and another which is length padded with the prefix.  Use the unique attribute to prevent duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have to columns And the primary key is for them both to be unique like that :

```
    CREATE TABLE yourtable (
        characs CHAR(3) Not null DEFAULT 'EMP',
        id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY (characs,id)
      ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```